# How to iterate Hashmap with containing arraylist

Tags: java, hashmap

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I iterate over each Entry in a Map?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46898/how-do-i-iterate-over-each-entry-in-a-map)

i have map like

```
HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<String>> map = = new HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<String>>();
```

i want iterate this type of map
please give me example how to iterate this map

Comment: please search the site before asking a new question.

Comment: this does not seem to be duplicate since Arraylist is the value compared to  the other question which has string

Answer (score 22):

```
for (Map.Entry<String, ArrayList<String>> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    String key = entry.getKey();
    ArrayList<String> value = entry.getValue();
    for(String aString : value){
        System.out.println("key : " + key + " value : " + aString);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do like this:

```
for (Integer i : map.keySet())
   for (String s : map.get(i))
      System.out.println("key :" + i + " value: " + s);
```